# What do you call the part of a helmet that protect the eye?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the part of a helmet that protect the eye?

[image]

In the picture above, there's a part that seems to have been nailed on the helmet, it's the bottom part that protects the eyes. Is there a name for it? I am thinking there might be a name, because it seems to have been added to the helmet. Because it was added, I am thinking there might be a word for it.

Comment: The style of fastening on that helmet is called a rivet.https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rivet I Don't think its a later addition it's similar in style to many other helmets of the era such as those found in Viking burials.

Comment: @Sarriesfan, you mean rivets were used to affix the visor to the helmet (versus using nuts and bolts or welding).

Comment: @ Yes JBH blackbird suggests it's nailed on but they in this case they are rivets. Nuts and bolts would leave too much of a protrusion into the wearers skull if the Helmet was struck, rivets can be quite flush. There may also have been some form of welding involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Visor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visor)** (Definition from Merriam-Webster)

> 1 : the front piece of a helmet especially : a movable upper piece
>
> 2a : a projecting front on a cap or headband for shading the eyes
>
> b : a usually movable flat sunshade attached at the top of an automobile windshield
>
> 3a : a face mask
>
> b : disguise

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's a moveable visor, I think it's a fixed eye guard piece a style used in Early Medieval helmets such as those used by the Saxon or Vikings.

Comment: @Sarriesfan, the definition is a front piece of a helmet.  The definition notes that it is "especially" defined as a moveable piece - but it needn't be.  The fixed portion in the OP's picture is a visor.  It's simply not a moveable visor.  Compare to [this Greek helmet](https://www.ancientsculpturegallery.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/0f396e8a55728e79b48334e699243c07/h/0/h003_5.jpg) which does not have a visor, just cut-outs for the eyes.